# Getting current location as 0.0, 0.0

Tags: android

As the title suggest I'm getting my current location as 0.0,0.0 when I check in LogCat. I have tried every solution given on net but not getting any solution. Please help. My code is given below, I have given all permission in Manifest also. Any help would be really appreciated.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GPStracker gpsTracker;
    private Location mLocation;
    double latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Checking permission is allowed or not
        int Permission_All = 1;

        String[] Permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if(!hasPermissions(this, Permissions)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Permissions, Permission_All);
        }

        gpsTracker = new GPStracker(MapsActivity.this);
        // checking GPS is enabled or not//
        gpsTracker.chkGPSorNetworkEnabled();
        mLocation = gpsTracker.getLocation();
        if(mLocation!=null) {
         latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
         longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("I'm here..."));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context!=null && permissions!=null){
            for(String permission: permissions){
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return  false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

GPStracker.java

```
public class GPStracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled =false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled =false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPStracker(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    // Class to check GPS/Location is enabled or not //
    public  void chkGPSorNetworkEnabled(){

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        String gpsMsg = "Please Enable your GPS/Location Service";
        String netMsg = "Please Enable your Network Service";

        if(!isGPSEnabled){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setMessage(gpsMsg);

            dialog.setPositiveButton("GPS Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    context.startActivity(gpsIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }else if(!isNetworkEnabled){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setMessage(netMsg);

            dialog.setPositiveButton("Network Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
                    context.startActivity(gpsIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            getLocation();
        }

    }


    //Create a GetLocation Method //
    public  Location getLocation(){
        try{
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            //chkGPSorNetworkEnabled();
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

                if(isGPSEnabled){
                    if(location==null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000,10,this);
                        if(locationManager!=null){
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if location is not found from GPS than it will found from network //
                if(location==null){
                    if(isNetworkEnabled){

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000,10,this);
                        if(locationManager!=null){
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return  location;
    }

    // followings are the default method if we imlement LocationListener //
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String Provider, int status, Bundle extras){

    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String Provider){

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String Provider){

    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your manifest to see all the permissions?

Comment: you need to implement `onBind()` and return an instance of `IBinder`; else the service will not bind.

Comment: Martin Zeitler can you please tell how as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onLocationChanged() callback method to listen the current location updates. In that method, location instance will give you both latitude and longitude. Add the marker to map also in that same method. You'll need map instance and send that over to GPStracker class via constructor when you create the instance in MapsActivity

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    mMap.clear();
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("I'm here..."));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            latlng, 17.0f)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Location API, try using FusedLocationProviderAPI which is latest and accurate as it optimized the way location is getting fetched. and for the sake of understanding whether the code is working or not try opening Map app and then press GPS button when you get the location then try running your app. Let me know if that helps or not.But i would highly recommend you to use FusedLocationProviderAPI.